# Разбор слова "банка"

Tags: словообразование, морфемика

Возник спор - как правильно разобрать по составу слово "банка":

1. корень - банк, окончание - а
2. корень -бан, суффикс -к, окончание - а.

Я склоняюсь к варианту 1, а коллега - к варианту 2

Answer (score 2):

Слово это непроизводное, так что суффикса в нём не выделяют. Схожий случай наблюдаем, к примеру, со словом *палка.* Эти и подобные непроизводные слова следует отличать от производных слов типа *свечка,* где *-к-* – суффикс.

Answer (score 1):

Можно, конечно, и не выделять суффикс (синхронический подход), чтобы школьников, слабо владеющих этимологией, не мучить... Но слова баночка, баночный наводят на некоторые размышления.
С исторической же точки зрения банка - однокоренное с "баня" превоначально означавшее "ванна", сосуд для воды. Так что я тоже склоняюсь к разбору "бан-к-а".

Comment: Всё-таки для школьников лучше, наверное, давать синхронию, а не диахронию. Меня тоже смутили -очк и -очн. Но вот если суф.-очк встречается довольно часто, то -очн - посложнее. Может быть, следует говорить о беглости гласных и чередовании согласных в корне, а К и Н рассматривать как самостоятельные суфиксы? Да и как на тестировании подобные слова рассматриваются? А вот про то, что "баня" и "банка" - однокоренные, я не знала: всё думала, с каким словом связать? Спасибо.

Comment: Синхронический подход придуман не для школьников. Это членение слова в современном языке. Корень здесь банк. При словообразовании наблюдается чередование к//ч, о//нуль звука.

Comment: В морфемных и словообразовательных словарях - синхронический подход.Правда, бывают у авторов и расхождения в мнениях.